# Increase SELECT performance for table with only primary keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 8 columns, as shown below in the create statement.

Rows have to be unique, that is, no two rows can have the exact same value in each column. To this end I defined each column to be a Primary Key.

However, performing a select as show below takes extremely long as, i suppose, MySQL will have to scan each row to find results. As the table is pretty large, this takes a lot of time.

Do you have any suggestion how I could increase performance?

EDIT create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `volatilities` (
`instrument` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`baseCurrencyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tenor` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tenorUnderlying` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`strike` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`evalDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`volatility` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`underlying` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY   (`instrument`,`baseCurrencyId`,`tenor`,`tenorUnderlying`,`strike`,`evalDate`,`volatility`,`underlying`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Select statement:

```
SELECT evalDate,
max(case when strike = 0.25 then volatility end) as '0.25'
FROM niels_testdb.volatilities
WHERE 
instrument = 'Swaption' and tenor = '3M' 
and tenorUnderlying = '3M' and strike = 0.25
GROUP BY 
evalDate
```

Comment: Please show your create table statement.  A table can have only one primary key.  What do you mean by:  "I defined each column to be a Primary Key"?

Comment: The create statement looks like: 

`CREATE TABLE 'niels_testdb'.'my_table' ( 'column1' INT NOT NULL , 'column2' INT NOT NULL , 'column3' INT NOT NULL , 'column4' INT NOT NULL , 'column5' INT NOT NULL , 'column6' INT NOT NULL , 'column7' INT NOT NULL , 'column8' INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8') );`

Comment: That `create table` statement will not work because you are using single quotes where no quotes at all are necessary.

Comment: The actual output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE niels_testdb.my_table` will help us here...  With your example above, MySQL would be able to use the index for `column1` since it is the leftmost column in the composite key. I suspect there is more to this though...

Comment: Your create statement won't work, did you mean backticks (\`) rather than single quotes(')? Either way that's not a primary key on each column, that's a primary key on every column(1 primary key, eight columns covered). I seriously recommend looping up how to create unique constraints instead of misusing primary keys in this way. Your primary key is supposed to be your rows identifier for the database engine(which explains why it's taking so long to return a row).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, the `SHOW CREATE` return is now written in my original question.

Comment: @NMeibergen That _can't be_ the real output from executing the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`.  The quoting is all wrong and MySQL would never produce output like that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Sorry, I messed up. The return is now corretly in the question.

Comment: Could you explain WHY you need a composite primary key of all columns?

Comment: And what _exact query_ are you trying to execute? When using a compound key, order matters if MySQL is not asked to lookup every column in the compound key.  The multi-column PK is suspicious here.

Comment: @AlexandreSantes: I used primary keys on all the columns as i want uniqueness over all of these. I then read that this was the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: The select statement is also included in the question. I am really not familiar with the deeper workings of SQL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your requirements is that all the rows need to have unique values. So that is why you created the table with composite primary keys for all columns. But your table WOULD allow duplicated values for every column, as long as the rows themselves were unique.

Take a look at this sql fiddler post: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ae6

In there you'll see that the column instrument and tenor do have duplicate values.

I'd say you need to investigate more how unique keys work and what primary keys are.

My suggestion is to re-think your requirements and investigate what needs to be unique and why and have a different structure to support your decision. Composite primary keys, in this case, is not the way to go.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I am now considering to add a primary key column containing the md5 sum of all other columns. In that way uniqueness will be satisfied. I will indeed perform a deeper investigation upon the working of unique keys.

Comment: Sorry, but MD5 will not do what you want because of collisions.